# Target of the bootstrap variances

Tags: r, variance, bootstrap

I have this bootstrap:

```
library(ggplot2)

n <- 30
set.seed(1)
orig_mean <- 1
orig_sd <- 2
X <- rnorm(n, mean = orig_mean, sd = orig_sd)
set.seed(NULL)

# Bootstrapping
m_reps <- 20000
boot_means <- c()
boot_vars <- c()
for (i in 1:m_reps) {
  current_sample <- sample(X, n, replace = T)
  boot_means <- append(boot_means, mean(current_sample))
  boot_vars <- append(boot_vars, var(current_sample))
}
boot_means <- as.data.frame(boot_means) #for plotting
boot_vars <- as.data.frame(boot_vars)
```

The central limit theorem tells us that those bootstrapped means $\bar{x}$ should be $\bar{X} \sim N\left(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n} \right)$. We can see this with the plot of $\bar{X} \sim N\left(1, \frac{2^2}{30} \right)$ on top of the bootstrapped means' histogram:

```
ggplot(boot_means, aes(x = boot_means)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(density)), bins = 20, color = "black", fill = "white") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(
    mean = orig_mean, sd = orig_sd/sqrt(n)))
```

The bell curve does not precisely line up with the histogram, but it is close.

I would like to do something like this with the variance. The variance histogram is:

```
ggplot(boot_vars, aes(x = boot_vars)) +
  geom_histogram(
    bins = 20, color = "black", fill = "white")
```

This is where I'm stuck. Is that a chi-squared distribution? And how do I set up a "target" curve like I did with the bootstrapped means?

What I'm really looking for is to figure out what the distribution is of bootstrapped variances. From there the coding should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: See the last sentence of the answer to the linked question for the answer for the type of distribution. Non-statistical coding-type questions are off-topic here, but you should be able to adapt the code you wrote for the distribution of sample mean values to the chi-square distribution associated with sample variances.

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/484875/28500) might also be helpful.